# Crystal report c#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, report

what I want to do is insert data in crystal report, the challenge is on how can I achieve that.

my data is

```
Jan 1, Number, Name
Jan 2, Number, Name
Jan 4, Number, Name
Jan 5, Number, Name
Jan 7, Number, Name
```

what I want to do is regardless of my data, I want to display in my crystal report the whole month.

so the expected output is

```
Jan 1, Number, Name
Jan 2, Number, Name
Jan 2, Null, Null
Jan 4, Number, Name
Jan 5, Number, Name
Jan 2, Null, Null
Jan 7, Number, Name
Jan 8, Null , Null
...
Jan 31, Null , Null
```

,is it possible to do this on crystal report?

I can generate it using select * from my queries, but i dont know how to fill in the missing values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to create a date table once for the dates you need, then you can join to your data.

Ex. `select * from [DateTable] left outer join [your queries] on [DateTable].date=[your queries].date`

Here is an example how to create date table once for 10 years period starting from the current year:

```
DECLARE @StartDate  date = '20210101';

DECLARE @CutoffDate date = DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(YEAR, 10, @StartDate));

;WITH seq(n) AS 
(
  SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT n + 1 FROM seq
  WHERE n < DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @CutoffDate)
),
d(d) AS 
(
  SELECT DATEADD(DAY, n, @StartDate) FROM seq
),
src AS
(
  SELECT
    TheDate         = CONVERT(date, d),
    TheDay          = DATEPART(DAY,       d),
    TheDayName      = DATENAME(WEEKDAY,   d),
    TheWeek         = DATEPART(WEEK,      d),
    TheISOWeek      = DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,  d),
    TheDayOfWeek    = DATEPART(WEEKDAY,   d),
    TheMonth        = DATEPART(MONTH,     d),
    TheMonthName    = DATENAME(MONTH,     d),
    TheQuarter      = DATEPART(Quarter,   d),
    TheYear         = DATEPART(YEAR,      d),
    TheFirstOfMonth = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(d), MONTH(d), 1),
    TheLastOfYear   = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(d), 12, 31),
    TheDayOfYear    = DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, d)
  FROM d
)
SELECT * into dbo.DateTable
 FROM src
  ORDER BY TheDate
  OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Comment: Thanks mate! I've just thought of adding datas in my database and just pass a null value there, but this seems to save me from running slow on my program.